# R Studio Error :- (Java):Could not initialize class com.miraisolutions.xlconnect.workbook

Tags: java, r, rjava, xlconnect

I have to use XLConnect package for my work. XLconnect Package is perfectly installed and all other package dependencies are also installed.

This package was working fine some time ago but now this is not able to read my files.

Also, this package has java dependency and my R software and java both are 64 bit. Also, both are configured correctly.

Please suggest what could be  the possible reason for this error.

This is the exact error which I'm getting.

Error:NoclassDefFoundError (Java): could not initialize class com.miraisolutions.xlconnect.workbook